# Cannot find files created using QStandardPath on android device

Tags: android, c++, qt

I'm developing an app on android using Qt 5.15.0. My app creates a database and some other files using **QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation**. everything works fine from the code side: debug output makes me think the files are there and that the app is using them. The problem is that when I search from the PC inside the smartphone folders I cannot find the files created. So this makes me think I am not writing to the folder I'm expecting to.

This is my code:

```
    appDataPath = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
    QDir directory;
    if (!directory.exists(appDataPath + QStringLiteral("/DATABASE")))
        directory.mkpath(appDataPath + QStringLiteral("/DATABASE"));
    if (!directory.exists(appDataPath + QStringLiteral("/DATA")))
        directory.mkpath(appDataPath + QStringLiteral("/DATA"));
    qDebug() << "Percorso: " << appDataPath << " dir exists:" << directory.exists(appDataPath + QStringLiteral("/DATABASE"));
    QFile f( appDataPath + "/DATABASE/Prova.txt"  );
    if( f.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly ) )
    {
        f.write( "Ciao" );
        f.close();
    }
    if( f.error() != QFileDevice::NoError )
         qDebug() << QString("Error writing file '%1':").arg(appDataPath + "/DATABASE/Prova.txt") <<  f.errorString();
```

I also write a file that I read at startup and I can read from it so I assume the file is present and is not saved as temporary.
The output is:

```
D/MyApp(17849): Percorso:  "/data/data/org.qtproject.example/files"  dir exists: true
```

Now I suppose I can find my files in this directory inside the phone in this folder:

```
Questo PC\Samsung Galaxy J3 (2016)\Phone\Android\data\org.qtproject.example\files
```

But there are no directories or files inside. I bet I am missing some trivial things.

I am giving the app these permission:

```
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that

```
QStandardPaths::AppLocalDataLocation, QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation
```

don't give the correct path to the app's file folder. I encountered the same issue with Qt 5.14.1. While QStandardPaths gave me

```
/data/user/0/com.mycompany.myapp/files
```

a call via a QAndroidJniObject to the java side gave me

```
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.mycompany.myapp/files
```

Using the latter all directories and files were created correctly. I suggest to either try my work-around with

```
QtNative.activity().getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath();
```

in an added java class and call it through a QAndroidJniObject or report this as a bug to Qt.
Nevertheless, there might be another solution to the problem I'm not aware of.